# Blank Layout Preview in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Ok. So I started migrating my works from Eclipse to Android Studio. But starting a new project consumed so much of my time already. The layout preview is not working, please see attached image:
[image]

And here's the XML code for that layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried changing the device, themes and Android versions. But nothing seems to fix my problem. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code of the .xml layout as well :-)

Comment: Works fine for me (I replaced the resource references with my own, random ones). Are you sure all the referenced resources (two layouts and a menu) are there? Doesn't the "Text" view (changed in the bottom of Design window) give you any errors?